# Read file line by line from SFTP

Tags: c#, file-io, sftp, memorystream

I have to read files from SFTP. I am downloading files in memory stream and then reading line by line:

```
MemoryStream memStream = sftpObj.DownloadFile(sftpSettings.DataDirectory + '/' + fileName);
```

This works fine for small files but i can have files which are above 1 GB in size in which case I get out of memory exception for my memory stream.

Is there a way that I can read files line by line from SFTP so I can save them locally?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an SFTP client that provides ReadFile function (in opposite to DownloadFile) and provides random access to remote files. Then you read the file in small chunks and process those chunks locally. Our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-sftp.php) offers such client.